# How to send the value via url to helper.php when i click a href link in the default.php?

Tags: component, php, fix-my-code

I want send the value via URL when i click a href tag and get the file(pdf/docs) from the database and how to fetch the file in the database.my default.php code :

```
<?php foreach($view_docs as $view_result) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php 
                                $doc_id_value = $view_result->doc_id;
                                $loc_doc_name = array('1'=>'Education','2'=>'Certification','3'=>'Client Paperwork','4'=>'Invoice');
                                echo $loc_doc_name[$doc_id_value];
                             ?>
                            <td><?php echo $view_result->doc_id; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo code is here ?>"><?php echo $view_result->name; ?></a></td>
                            <td><?php echo $view_result->created; ?></td>

                        </th>
                    </tr>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My Database Img is:
[image]

default.php view:
when i click the **name** field,the corresponding file to be downloaded
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope question is too wide for a simple answer.

When you click on a href tag, a controller receives the call. The controller can call the helper to retrieve the PDF Blob and return to the controller the binary object. And, finally the controller response returns the generated PDF output.

Comment: now i got the current page url and add the value(Ex:url?doc_name=chap6.pdf).Thank your response